# Help exporting regression output from STATA to LaTeX

Tags: input, typewriter

How can I export my regression output from STATA to LaTeX so that it looks like this:

[image]

And not like this:

[image]

Using estout gives me the second and cleaner table. I just want to export a table that looks the same as the regression output (with the input command, preferably)

Comment: Hello, please provide a minimal working example (see here https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with what you tried so far. It is quite unpleasant to see questions with very little information, adding information could result is a fester response from the helpers. "estout" seems to be some feature of the "STATA" software, when asking a question, try to be as clear as possible, most people don't know what you are working on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `listings` package. I allows for printing text documents inside a pdf without trying to compile the inserted text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
% The file containing the data is called STATAfile.txt
\lstinputlisting{STATAfile.txt}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start a log-file, export it as pdf and import it to Latex. 
Alternatively, you can try the `markdoc` command in Stata to convert the .smcl file to .tex.